# node js: alert on database update

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to make something like `console.log('Dear user, there was updates')`. I made basic console.log for now which is not what I'm looking for because I want from node to check if there was some update on database, not updating in function.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "test"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  //Update the address field:
  var sql = "UPDATE users SET name = 'lol2' WHERE name = 'lol'";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result.affectedRows + " record(s) updated");
  });
});
```

*edit: alert to console.log*

Comment: Does database update via your Node JS  code?

Comment: Yes it does. Why u asking?

Comment: In that case, you can write your update query in a single function and emit an event every time the update query runs. Something like 

 function updateTable () {
    
    var sql = "UPDATE users SET name = 'lol2' WHERE name = 'lol'";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result.affectedRows + " record(s) updated");
    process.emit("DB_UPDATED",result.affectedRows)
  });
 }

Comment: and listen for changes via process.on("DB_UPDATED",function(data){

  console.log(data.affectedRows +"rows updated);
})

Comment: It will be again the same... I dont want to put in function the constant query, I want nodejs to check for updates in database. Something like Administrator made UPDATE in db and nodejs will alert clients that prices changed in some products.

Comment: Are you looking for a seperate listener on the database ? Also why do you want that instead of something like a promise executed when database is updated ?

Comment: AFAIK the only other way is to either write an update trigger for the table and execute your node script from it or periodically ping your database from your node script to check for changes. Both of the solutions are equally bad.

Answer (score 0):

Alert wont work in Node.js Instead sent a response back to client side with the total affected of results. And based results, show alert with the count received.

eg.

```
 return res.status(200).return(result.affectedRows);
```

and in client side

```
if(datareceived > 0){
 alert(`Dear user, there was ${datareceived} price updates moment ago`)
}else{ // your other logic }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but im trying to solve problem with not alerting or console.log but the node which is checking for updates in database and then making some notification for user.

Comment: @can1 do you want to notify all the users or just to a particular user who issued request ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey I want to notify all users when admin updates the db.

Comment: Yes,,, Sockets is what you all need.